# Django settings: DATABASE_URL is not working

Tags: django, heroku, django-settings

I just created a test application in Heroku so that I can stay in the same Django project, but quickly switch back and forth between connecting to my production database and my testing app database. I created an environment variable on my laptop using `export:TEST_DATABASE_URL="..."`, but even with this below code I am still connected to my production database when I run my Django project on localhost. Does anyone know how i can accomplish this?

```
# ~~~ PROD SETTINGS ~~~
# DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
# DEBUG = 'False'

# ~~~ TEST SETTINGS ~~~
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['TEST_DATABASE_URL']
DEBUG = 'True'


# tried commenting this code out so it doesn't use the local sqlite file
# DATABASES = { # Use this to use local test DB # todo: prod doesn't havea access to django_session...
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#     }
# }
```

**Procfile:**

```
release: python3 manage.py migrate
web: daphne django_project.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python3 manage.py runworker channels --settings=django_project.settings -v2
```

Comment: Can you mention your OS name and share some details about how you actually set the environment variable in it?

Comment: For sure, I'm on Windows but I run all the Django commands in the Ubuntu subsytem (like `python3 manage.py runserver 0:8000`). I have a `DATABASE_URL` environment var, and a `TEST_DATABASE_URL` one. And even with the above code, when i use the runserver command for port 8000, it is still showing me data from my production app. ALSO, when i debug the `DATABASE_URL` variable in settings.py, and can see that it is printing the test database url, so i'm not sure what's going wrong

Comment: I just added my Procfile to the question. I also have 2 git remotes in my current repo, one for prod and one for test. But i don't think that should make a difference for local development

Comment: Still struggling with this, seems like it should be an easy thing to configure

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. Even though I was setting `DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']` in settings.py, Django ignored that. When running the app locally I had to use `export DATABASE_URL={my database credential}` in my ubuntu terminal for my localhost to use my test database