# Django : Currently there is no database set to DATABASE_URL

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I am working on a Django project for my client and I have to refactor the custom middleware to django authentication ( login ) and Django views.

In the case of middleware, I put a passphrase which acts like a password and then it authorizes the users and everything works fine.
now I changed the code from middleware to Django authentication to let the users login and then do the other logic.
I was searching for the question on SO and I found this problem [Django settings: DATABASE_URL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66866522/django-settings-database-url-is-not-working)

I tried to do the same but it is not fixing the issue.
This is the code that tells me why my database url is not set:

```
def message_check_db(request, **kwargs):
    try:

        DB_Found = False
        DB_Connected = False
        result = run_command()
        print("\n RESULT  :", result)
        for (env, url) in os.environ.items():
            if env.startswith('HEROKU_POSTGRESQL'):
                DB_Found = True
                print("\n FOUND DB :", DB_Found)

                formatted_Data = []
                for formatted_String in str(result.stdout).split('=== '):

                    start_DbName = formatted_String.find("HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_")
                    end_DbName = formatted_String.find("\\nPlan")
                    DbName = formatted_String[start_DbName:end_DbName]


                    start_AddOn = formatted_String.find("Add-on:")
                    end_AddOn = formatted_String.find("\\n\\n")
                    AddOn = formatted_String[start_AddOn:end_AddOn].replace('Add-on:           ', "")

                    formatted_Data.append({
                        "name": DbName.replace(", DATABASE_URL", ""),
                        "addon": AddOn
                    })

                color_DB = getDbName(env)

                current_DB = getDbName('DATABASE_URL')
                for data in formatted_Data:
                    if env == data['name'] and color_DB == current_DB:
                        DB_Connected = True
                        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, data['name'] + " / " + data['addon'])
        if not DB_Found :
            print("\n DB NOT FOUND :", DB_Found)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, "Currently there is no database set to DATABASE_URL")
        elif not DB_Connected :
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, "Currently you are running app on localhost")
    except:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "Currently there is no database found")
```

This is the code which let the user login:

```
def userLogin(request):
        SESSION_TIMEOUT = AuthToggle.objects.first()
        nuclear = AuthToggle.objects.first()
        faravahar = AuthToggle.objects.first()
        isLoggedIn = request.user.is_authenticated
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        if request.method == "POST":
            if username and password:
                request.session['loggedIn'])
                user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    print("\n User in middleware view :", user)
                    request.session['last_touch'] = datetime.now()
                    request.session['loggedIn'] = True
                    messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in!')

                    notification.messages_print(
                        'info', 'New session of ' + str(SESSION_TIMEOUT.timeout) + ' minutes has started')
                return redirect('portal')
```

the userLogin function gets called when a user try to login through this piece of code:

```
def index(request):
    auth_toggel = AuthToggle.objects.first().faravahar
    faravahar = AuthToggle.objects.first().faravahar
    nuclear = AuthToggle.objects.first().nuclear
    context = {
        "faravahar": faravahar,
        "nuclear": nuclear,
    }
    if not nuclear:
        if request.method == "POST":
            passphrase = request.POST.get('passphrase')
            gateway = False
            protection = AuthToggle.objects.first().is_protected # this means protection is turned On
            global attempts, maxAttempts, enableTimer
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            if username and password:
                request.session['loggedIn'])
                user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    print("\n User in Index view :", user)
                    userLogin(request)
                    messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in!')
```

NOTE: When I remove the login() method from other views other than the index(request) function then it doesn't display the error related to DATABASE_URL but still it doesn't let the user login or be redirected to the portal URL. When I keep the login() method in all of those places, then it doesn't login the user and also displays the error of **Currently there is no database set to DATABASE_URL** which is quite confusing.

Can someone explain why is it happening?